# Return non-existing row with 0 or NULL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In this query below, not every month shows up for every country, because some countries have low volumes of business and there are no `id`s to count. However, I need each month to show up for each plan type, transaction type, year, month and country.

Is there a way to accomplish this in BigQuery, showing counts as 0 when they don't exist?

```
select
extract(year from closedate) as year,
extract (month from closedate) as month,

case billing_country__c
when 'USA' THEN 'United States' ELSE billing_country__c
END AS country,

case
when account_type_sold__c = 'Starter' then 'Starter'
when account_type_sold__c = 'Business' then 'Business'
when account_type_sold__c in('Enterprise','Legacy - Enterprise') then 'Enterprise'
else 'Other'
end as plan_type,

case
when type = 'web_trial' then 'Web Trial'
when type = 'buy_now' then 'Buy Now'
else 'other'
end as transaction_type,

count(distinct(id)) as opps_all

from `company.sales_table`
group by year, month, billing_country__c, plan_type, transaction_type
```

Comment: will you consider a a prepared query (or temp table) with prepared template columns and values, and then use a 'left out join' to join with your query?

Comment: @al-dann yes I suppose this is one approach. I'd like to avoid a temp table and proceed with a more stable solution if one exists, but this is a good workaround.

Comment: Well, just to clarify - it might not be necessary to make such table permanent. It might be created at run time (from the code) - some kind of a usual 'with temp_table as (....)' and then ordinary select (as in your case) where that 'temp_table' is used for the left outer join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below uses the `GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY` function to create a row for each month between two dates. Once you flatten the date array, you can join this to your data to show zeros for months that don't have any data.

```
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT
    1 AS order_id,
    DATE('2024-01-01') AS close_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    1 AS order_id,
    DATE('2024-03-01') AS close_date
),

reporting_months AS (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(year from reporting_date) as year,
    EXTRACT(month from reporting_date) as month,
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE('2024-01-01'), DATE('2024-03-01'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS reporting_date
)

SELECT
  r.year,
  r.month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) as order_count
FROM reporting_months AS r
LEFT JOIN sample_data AS s
ON
  EXTRACT(year from s.close_date) = r.year
  AND EXTRACT(month from s.close_date) = r.month
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

output:

```
year    month   order_count
2024    1       1
2024    2       0
2024    3       1
```